# python scripts are kept alive for no reason centos 7 php nodejs

Tags: php, python, node.js, linux, centos7

I am running centos 7 webserver for one of my clients inside there is a python script that is start from a php script. (this process can happen a few thousand times a minute).

For whatever reason the python scripts are left opened in the server after they finish running each one of them for something like 30 seconds.

This puts a huge load on the server and it's causing me many issue, i tried adding in exit() and sys.exit to the end of the code and in the appropriate function areas but it does not seem to work.

I know that the process are kept a live because i can see them using the top command and they also already made the server shutdown 2 times.

my question is how do i go about shutting down this python scripts what am i missing?

Comment: Are the Python scripts using the multiprocessing module? And what method are you using to start these scripts from PHP?

Comment: right now no multiproccessing module,(spouse to be add later on).
im using shell_exec in php with esacpe shell before

Comment: I am wondering how all these came together, php, python and nodejs

Comment: not much i can do about it, the project was bought off as a whole website i moving most of it to node but some integral parts that use python libraries are no as easy to recreate in js.